# error in SSIS - [SQL query execution task] Error: The binding name of the results must be zero for the complete result set and the XML results

Tags: sql-server, ssis, business-intelligence

I have an Execute SQL task that returns "Full result set". Despite that, the task fails. Please how can I fix it ?

[SQL query execution task] Error: The binding name of the results must be zero for the complete result set and the XML results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Click on ResultSet in the Execute SQL Task, click Add. In the 'ResultSetName' column, enter the exact name of the columnname that you are retrieving or simply give it 0. In the 'variablename', select the variable you created to map the data returned.